# Compute taper joint resistance to slipping

Tags: classical-mechanics, friction, torque

In toolholding a standard method is to use a taper joint. The shank of the tool is tapered and fits into a socket in the spindle like this:

[image]

Typically both the shank and the socket are made of polished steel.

I want to know how to compute the resistance of the shank to turning in the socket (slipping) as a function of the force holding the shank in the socket, the friction of the two surfaces and torque being applied to the tool.

Note that there may actually be an equation or two different values because if the tool is rotating and stops short then it will cause a shock or instantaneous force which will have different characteristics than a steady force.

On a side note I am interested in learning more about the binding angle of the taper. If the taper is narrow then when tool is forced into the socket, it will bind and not fall out by gravity. If the taper has a large angle, however, it will not bind and the tool will always fall out by gravity if it is not held in somehow. How can I determine the threshold between a binding and non-binding angle?

Comment: Hi.   This seems to be a question for engineeringSE in my opinion, I can't see where any  physics concept comes into it, sorry

Comment: @CountTo10 You could read the tags on the question.